# How bad is settling a city on floodplains?

Tags: civilization-6

Is there a penalty to doing so and if so what? Do your city centre improvements (Monument, Granary, etc) periodically get damaged? If so, how bad and how to repair?

Answer (score 4):

**There is no penalty for settling on one type of tile of vs another.** There are varying stats and bonuses for the different tile types but no penalties.

Building on top of a resource will give you access to that resource. [See here for example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmezZ.jpg)

Some tile types are favored more than others, such as plains hills, as your city will start with 2 hammers 2 food.

More information on [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/7tbzof/civ_6_about_building_cities_on_top_of_resources/) if you're curious.

Comment: "Building on top of a resource will give you access to that resource" - Well that's something I wish I knew when I started playing civ... I always assumed you'd lose the resource and just settled next to them :)

Comment: Worth noting that this answer changes slightly with the addition of the Gathering Storm DLC where floodplains can actually flood and damage your tiles which becomes a potential trade-off to consider. You can eventually build preventative buildings that can help or even benefit you for being on the tiles.